# How to Get Black Borders in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, iphone-5

When I first updated Xcode and tested my app in the iPhone 5 simulator, the app ran perfectly with black borders at the top and bottom. Then, something popped up asking if I wanted Xcode to auto-resize the app so that it would fit the entire screen. I clicked yes, and now everything is messed up. Is there a way to get the borders back? I want to submit an update for my app as soon as possible. Thank you!

Comment: have u used any local git or maintained the code on some repositories...

Comment: If you do this, Apple will not accept your app.

Comment: @Fogmeister it's only applicable if the app is submitted AFTER May 1st (2013). If it was already on the App Store, then black bars are automaticaly added

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the file Default-568h@2x.png from your project.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work. I think xcode does it automatically but there must be a setting to prevent that from happening

Comment: The answer is definitely right. Make sure you do a Clean Build Folder. And maybe delete the app from the simulator and run again.

Comment: If you go in the simulator and click reset content and settings, it fixes the problem

Comment: @BoltClock: it asks you if you want Xcode to add it. If you don't, you'll get the black bars. If you do, the app will take up the entire screen without bars.

Comment: @Scott: Does it just add a blank image with those dimensions, or does it base it off the original Default@2x.png? (I haven't had the opportunity to try it myself yet.)

Comment: @BoltClock: It's a solid black image.

Answer (score 5):

4 steps:

- Uncheck the Target Membership of the Default-568h@2x.png file in the File Inspector pane (or just remove the file).
- Do an (Option key) Clean Build Folder on the target, and a regular Clean as well.
- Delete the app from the Simulator.
- Rebuild the app and Run it.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that as of May 1 Apple requires the Default-568h@2x.png image in your application for submission to the App Store. Without that image you will receive an invalid binary rejection.

Answer (score 1):

A clean build folder can be tricky to find. Normaly you just see under Project > Clean . BUT when you keep your ALTkey pressed it will change into Clean Build Folder!